# Merging two dataframes to get one dataframe using multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have the two dataframes below:

```
incoming_table:
| first_name | last_name | account_number | phone  | email
| --------   | --------  | -------------  | ------ | -----
| John       | Smith     | 12344557       | 123456 | hello@hello.co.uk
| Jane       | Smith     | 12335887       | 891011 | you@mint.co.uk
| Sarah      | Apple     | 25246555       | 789101 | someone@yellow.co.uk
| George     | Bush      | 45425445       | 112131 | anyone@green.com
| Jacob      | May       | 45543634       | 415161 | everyone@grey.com
```

```
main_table:
| first_name | last_name | account_number | phone  | email
| --------   | --------  | -------------  | ------ | -----
| John       | Smith     | 97634437       | 123456 | hello@hello.co.uk
| Jane       | Smith     | 76735423       | 111111 | you@mint.co.uk
| Simon      | Wilkinson | 87875564       | 159263 | all@red.co.uk
| Ben        | Google    | 85345757       | 189147 | only@pink.com
| Jacob      | May       | 45543634       | 415161 | everyone@grey.com
```

I would like to merge the two dataframes, where the `first_name` and `last_name` match, but `account_number` doesn't not match, given they match on phone or on email as well.

So my final table should be:

```
| first_name | last_name | account_number | phone  | email
| --------   | --------  | -------------  | ------ | -----
| John       | Smith     | 97634437       | 123456 | hello@hello.co.uk
| Jane       | Smith     | 12335887       | 891011 | you@mint.co.uk
```

As "John Smith" matches with first name, last name, but account number doesn't not match but phone or email do, the same with "Jane Smith" but only the email matches but satisfies the criteria. However, "Jacob May" does not as both tables have the same account number.

However I don't know how to do "not on account number" and for multiple conditions for (OR).

I have tried using this but it didn't work as I can't find a way to create conditions:

```
final_df = main_table.merge(incoming_table, on=['first_name', 'last_name'], how = 'inner')
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge and then filter:

```py
final_df = main_table.merge(incoming_table, on=['first_name', 'last_name'], how = 'inner')

# Filter different account numbers
final_df = final_df[final_df.account_number_x != final_df.account_number_y]

# Filter for same email or phone
final_df = final_df[(final_df.phone_x == final_df.phone_y) | (final_df.email_x == final_df.email_y)]
```

You will end up with columns:

- first_name
- last_name
- account_number_x
- account_number_y
- phone_x
- phone_y
- email_x
- email_y

_x : main table
_y : incoming table

You can change the _x, _y adding `suffixes=('_x', '_y')` to the merge statement, with the values you want.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this has worked, however I have noticed where there are blanks for phone or email and if both phone or emails are blanks it matches, so I am trying to do this but it's not working:

final_df = final_df[(np.where((final_df['phone_x'] =='') | (final_df['phone_y'] == ''), '',
                                               final_df.phone_x == final_df.phone_y)) |
                            (np.where((final_df['email_x'] =='') | (final_df['email_y'] == ''), '',
                                              final_df.email_x == final_df.email_y))]

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
# Step 1
# merge on first_name, last_name, phone
merged_df = main_table.merge(incoming_table, 
                             left_on=['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone'], 
                             right_on=['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone'],
                             suffixes=('_main', '_incoming'),
                             how='inner')

# merge on first_name, last_name, email
merged_df_email = main_table.merge(incoming_table, 
                                   left_on=['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'], 
                                   right_on=['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'],
                                   suffixes=('_main', '_incoming'),
                                   how='inner')

# concatenate the two merged dataframes
merged_df = pd.concat([merged_df, merged_df_email]).drop_duplicates()

# Step 2
# filter out rows where account_number also matches
final_df = merged_df[merged_df.account_number_main != merged_df.account_number_incoming]

# Clean up the final dataframe, choose the columns you need and rename them accordingly.
final_df = final_df[['first_name', 'last_name', 'account_number_main', 'phone', 'email']]
final_df.columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'account_number', 'phone', 'email']
```

It will create a DataFrame where the first_name and last_name match, but the account_number does not, given that they match either on phone or email. I guess that the same person will not have multiple phone numbers or email addresses.